# Check on $_GET variable fails

Tags: php, html, forms, action

I am creating a PHP page, in one page I would like to show the main HTML based on which `$_GET["action"]`. However whatever which `if ($action == "xxx")` condition

```
// Action Judgement
$action = isset($_GET["action"]) ? $action : 'form';
$action = isset($action) && in_array($action, array('form', 'submit')) ? $action : 'form';

if($action == "form") { ?>
    // only html <form>...</form> codes here
<?php } elseif($action == "submit") { ?>
    // only php codes for processing here
<?php } ?>
```

If I put the URL like this `abc.php?action=submit`, the HTML codes are showing in the page. Is my coding wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first line is wrong. Fix it by replacing it by

```
$action = isset($_GET["action"]) ? $_GET["action"] : 'form';
```

or you could even improve it by taking

```
$action = ( isset($_GET["action"]) && !empty($_GET["action"]) ) ? $_GET["action"] : 'form';
```

or even better (as [Ben D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1096794/ben-d) suggested)

```
$action = !empty($_GET["action"]) ? $_GET["action"] : 'form';
```

Comment: You don't need to do both an `isset` and `empty` check - `empty` returns true if the variable is not set.

Comment: If you call the script via `abc.php?action` (without `=foobar`), then `isset()` returns true, but the value is yet empty. That may raise errors later.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me - I'm saying that you don't need the `isset` call: `!empty($_GET["action"])` will return false if the variable is empty (because it looks for variables that don't exist), so calling `isset` first is redundant:

`if ( isset($_GET["action"]) && !empty($_GET["action"]) )` is functionally exactly the same as `if (!empty($_GET["action"]) )`

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing variables and forms.

```
if($action == "form") {
    echo "only html <form>...</form> codes here";
} else if($action == "submit") {
    only php codes for processing here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$action = isset($_GET["action"]) ? $_GET['action'] : 'form';
$action = isset($action) && in_array($action, array('form', 'submit')) ? $action : 'form';
```